# How to map a function pointer to its definition?

Tags: c, ctags

When I'm going through source code I got a function pointer. So I used `ctags -R` but I didn't get the definition. It's like

```
int (*example)(struct arg1, struct arg2);
```

How can I get original function(definition)?

Comment: What original function?

Comment: That's a variable, it can be assigned many different functions.

Comment: I need definition of that mapped function

Comment: @OliCharlesworth op found a var in the source and can't find the declaration. | Just search for every line where the var is used and you will find the assignment.

Comment: @self. souce code is huge and split into many files

Comment: @SGG: It's not really clear what you're asking.  The contents of that variable can only be known at run-time, not compile-time (nor before).

Comment: @SGG Pick your favorite text editor, open all files and do a search all.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It is pretty obvious.

Comment: @self.: No it isn't; I'd ask the OP to clarify exactly what he/she is looking for.

Comment: I have a code that have the line `()example()`. example is mapped to which function? I mean declaration. @jweyrich is right

Comment: function pointers point to different function at different point of time. Ctags cannot do the dynamic analysis needed.You will have to look for last assignment to the function pointer. you should create a script using `grep "example \=" <source Files>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int (*example)(struct arg1, struct arg2);
```

Here the function pointer is declared but not assigned a value i.e. it is not pointing to any function. so in code there will be a statement that assigns a function to it so you can search for,

```
"example="
```

in the source code to know the function it is pointing to.

Comment: @SGG: You can always use **[grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)** or something similar available on your platform.

Comment: you mean `cat * | grep example =`

Comment: No need for `cat`. Just `cd project_dir; grep -rn "example =" *`, where `r` is for recursive search, and `n` to show line numbers.

Comment: got it. my problem is I don't know how to use grep

Comment: Try **[this tutorial](http://www.opensourceforu.com/2012/06/beginners-guide-gnu-grep-basics-regular-expressions/)** - Hopefully it will make it clear.

Comment: Or... you could get a sane IDE with "find in files" instead of bothering to learn some useless 1970s console mumbo-jumbo...

Comment: @Lundin: or that, although learning is always a positive thing. That is totally not 1970's mumbo-jumbo. In ages of cloud computing, virtual machines, docker, and so on, it's not uncommon to find yourself locked into a terminal (I bet you know that!) - though I discourage anyone changing code in production environments.

Answer (score 3):

```
int (*example)(struct arg1, struct arg2);
```

The line above declares a variable named `example` which is of type `int (*)(struct arg1, struct arg2)`. You can assign a compatible function pointer to it, for example:

```
int foo(struct arg1 a1, struct arg2 a2) {
    // irrelevant
}

int main(void) {
    int (*example)(struct arg1, struct arg2); // declare example as a function ptr
    struct arg1 a1;
    struct arg2 a2;
    example = &foo; // assign address of foo to it. BTW, `example = foo;` also works.
    example(a1, a2); // call foo
    return 0;
}
```

It is just like having another pointer, e.g: `int *example;`, but with a different type.

Comment: @jweyrich Thank you for your improvement. By the way, `example = foo;` also works.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Yep, the ampersand operator is optional there - I generally try to explicitly state the intention unless it takes too much effort. At the end it's just personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

Function Pointer are also just pointers which points to address.

> int (*example)(struct arg1, struct arg2);

that's declaration of the pointer not defintion.

for defintion you to search where the pointer is pointed like @learningC answered 
check where `example` is being assigned

Assuming your finding it before compiling(as your information is not complete why you want)

> VI / Vim, just type "/" or "?", followed by the word you're searching for.

EDIT:- [Find words](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-recursively-search-all-files-for-words/) to find patterns in multiple files check the link